# Google Dashboard claims that I have 26 open tabs, but I don't

Tags: google-chrome, google-dashboard

When I open the Google Dashboard to view the data associated with my account, under the Chrome tab it says that I have 26 open tabs.

I run Chrome on my phone, PC, and VM, and definitely don't have that many tabs opened concurrently.

When viewing "tabs from other devices" in Chrome, correct tabs are listed?

Is this a bug or am I missing something? How can it be reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google Dash click on sign out of all sessions and then check again the results.